# How Can I Distribute Jetty With My WAR Using Maven?

Tags: maven, jetty

I have maven building a web application successfully, which ends up with my war file in the target directory ready to be deployed in Jetty.

I currently give the war with an installation guide to clients that says "download and install Jetty and put the WAR in the right place etc etc".
However, some people have reported config issues or just don't want to have to download other software to run mine.

I'd rather give them a zip file that they can unzip and run.

Is it possible to configure maven to create a zip distribution for me that includes Jetty and my war file in the right place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[edit] The Codehaus is no more but Jetty found a home at the Eclipse Foundation years ago. http://www.eclipse.org/jetty

---

http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/mortbay/jetty/jetty-hightide/8.1.16.v20140903/jetty-hightide-8.1.16.v20140903.pom

line 46(ish) is where we pull the jetty-distribution from eclipse and unpack into an assembly directory and then the remaining lines there are were we add additional things to it

so to answer your question, yes you can, it is easy and jetty does it itself with the jetty-hightide distribution

Comment: the site is gone – maybe the new one has the same info somewhere? if you can find it again it would be nice to quote the relevant bits

Comment: there you go, that should get you going